# File css/js call based on specific page condition in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Is there way to file (css/js) call based on specific page condition in EJS, Or any flag using from router or condition based on URL in EJS file

***Note***: Below code is working fine when calling `/editor` page but it will break if go other page because of undefined '`isEditorPage`' variable . I think this practice is bad idea So I am searching for perfect way for this situation

**It is a common header - ejs file**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
 <%if (isEditorPage) { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/admin/editor.css">
 <% } %>
</head>
```

**Express router**

```
router.get('/editor', function(req, res){
    let isEditorPage = true;
    Blog.find({}, function(err, blog){
        res.render('admin/blog', {isEditorPage} );
    });
});
```

Comment: Try `{isEditorPage: isEditor}` or rename the variable `let isEditorPage = true;`

Comment: Thats is my typo error here , its working but it will be error on other page because of undefined isEditorPage variable , so Im asking for best way to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to check for existence of variable in an EJS template (using ExpressJS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372559/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-for-existence-of-variable-in-an-ejs-template-us)

Comment: @TGrif Brother Success , Please Answer this I can mark your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `typeof`:

```
<%if (typeof isEditorPage !== 'undefined') { %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/admin/editor.css">
<% } %>
```