# My 'errors' variable in ejs template causes 'undefined' error on page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

My 'errors' variable in ejs template causes 'undefined' error on page load

I have an ejs template for a contact-form with code to output errors via flash messages to the page when the form is not properly or completely filled out.

```
<%- messages('message', locals) %>

    <% if (errors !== undefined) { %>
    // Output the errors to the page
    <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <%= error.message %>
        </div>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

The code in my app.js file creates the 'errors' variable.

```
let errors = req.validationResult();

if (errors) {
    res.render('contact-form', {
        errors: errors
    });
```

For what it's worth, the 'messages.ejs' template contains the following code:

```
<div id="messages">
<% Object.keys(messages).forEach(function (type) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= type %>">
    <% messages[type].forEach(function (message) { %>
        <p><%= message %></p>
    <% }) %>
    </div>
<% }) %>
</div>
```

The line:

```
<% if (errors !== undefined) { %>
```

from the contact-form.ejs template is throwing the 'errors is not defined' error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to check for existence of variable in an EJS template (using ExpressJS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372559/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-for-existence-of-variable-in-an-ejs-template-us)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "undefined error" is referring to `errors.forEach`. The result of `validationResult()` is not an array of errors, it's an object with getters like `isEmpty()` and `array()`, so you may need to adjust your controller code slightly.

Check out [the docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-result-api.html) for some examples.

Comment: See edit above for clarification on the line that is throwing the 'errors is not defined' error.