# EJS do not error if value is not provided

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to add some EJS to a yaml file. I want to use a default value if a variable is not provided to EJS but can't figure out how. Here are two attempts, both of which fail with the following error message:

```
postgres_credentials_secret_name is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/paymahn/code/goldsky/strick/infra/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:662:12), <anonymous>:107:17)
    at anonymous (/Users/paymahn/code/goldsky/strick/infra/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:692:17)
    at Object.exports.render (/Users/paymahn/code/goldsky/strick/infra/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:423:37)
    at Immediate.run (/Users/paymahn/code/goldsky/strick/infra/node_modules/ejs/bin/cli.js:201:20)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21) {
  path: ''
}
```

attempt 1:

```
                  <% if(postgres_credentials_secret_name) { %>
                  name: <%- postgres_credentials_secret_name %>
                  <% } else { %>
                  name: graph-node-postgres-credentials
                  <% } %>
```

attempt 2:

```
                  name: <%- postgres_credentials_secret_name || 'graph-node-postgres-credentials' %>
```

How can I get EJS to not complain if a variable is not provided since I'm providing a default value in templating logic itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you are not sending `postgres_credentials_secret_name` from your server so it is not defined in the template. You can use `typeof postgres_credentials_secret_name` and see if it is `undefined`. Or you could use **`locals.postgres_credentials_secret_name`** see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372559/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-for-existence-of-variable-in-an-ejs-template-us)

```js
console.log(typeof postgres_credentials_secret_name)
console.log(typeof postgres_credentials_secret_name === 'undefined')
console.log(postgres_credentials_secret_name)
```

```
name: <%- typeof postgres_credentials_secret_name !== 'undefined' ? postgres_credentials_secret_name : 'graph-node-postgres-credentials' %>
```

alternatively you could use

```
name: <%- locals.postgres_credentials_secret_name ? postgres_credentials_secret_name : 'graph-node-postgres-credentials' %>
```

or even

```
name: <%- locals.postgres_credentials_secret_name || 'graph-node-postgres-credentials' %>
```

However, you could send something like an empty string then your approach would work

Comment: I find `if ("postgres_credentials_secret_name" in locals)` more readable, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: @3limin4t0r if writing a ternary then `locals.postgres_credentials_secret_name ? postgres_credentials_secret_name : 'graph-node-postgres-credentials'` doesn't look too bad or maybe even `locals.postgres_credentials_secret_name || 'graph-node-postgres-credentials'`

Comment: The final suggestion is probably the cleanest.